# How does the max HP increase from the Order of the Immortal mystic's Immortal Durability work?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, hit-points, mystic

This is about [the latest version (v3) of the mystic class from Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf).

Order of the Immortal mystics get the Immortal Durability feature at 1st level when they choose the subclass, part of which says:

> Starting at 1st level, your hit point maximum increases by 1 per mystic level.

**At 4th level, do I gain 4 total HP, or 1+2+3+4 for a total increase of 10 HP?**

Comment: Are you asking about the max HP increase specifically when going from level 3 to level 4? Or are you asking about the overall HP difference at level 4 compared to a mystic without it?

Answer (score 3):

### At 4th Level, you gain +4 total HP

The Immortal Durability feature is comparable to the Draconic Resilience feature of a Draconic Bloodline Sorcerer, in that both raise your HP maximum and AC.  The language for Draconic Resilience is clearer, possibly because it's officially published material:

> Draconic Resilience:
>   As magic flows through your body, it causes physical traits of your dragon ancestors to emerge. At 1st level, your hit point maximum increases by 1 and increases by 1 again whenever you gain a level in this class.

I believe the language in Immortal Durability ("your hit point maximum increases by 1 per mystic level.") is meant to be shorthand for the language used in Draconic Resilience ("your hit point maximum increases by 1 and increases by 1 again whenever you gain a level in this class.").  Presumably, they will use the more clear wording if the Mystic class is ever published.

This certainly makes most sense from a balance perspective, because if you continue to use the other method (1 + 2 + 3 + 4...), the feature will add a whopping 210 HP to your max by level 20!